SDK Tools unable to obtain desired data
When I used aptos-labs/ts-sdk, I encountered the following problems.
I want to obtain event-related data by scanning the number of blocks in a specified interval. However, when I use the event-related methods in the SDK to subscribe to events, the same range always gets different values.How can i solve this problem
I have used multiple methods to obtain events, but the results are not working. The data obtained is different every time.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
